# is there a function in excel to group values based on the data shown?

Tags: excel, sum, reliability

| Date | Running | SB | PM | DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-jan | 24 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 2-jan | 0 | 0 | 0 | 24 |
| 3-jan | 24 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 4-jan | 24 | 0 |  | 0 |
| 5-jan |  | 0 |  | 24 |

I need to calculate TTF which is time to failure needs to be calculated based on the running hrs which happens on 1jan, that becomes my TTF and then 24 becomes my failure again on 3jan I have running hrs and followed by it is DT, is there a way for me to sum randomly based on the gaps, if yes please help. thank you

Comment: Doesn't make sense. What is `TTF`? Can you explain how you are calculating `DT` column? Why 3-jan, 4-jan is zero in DT column?

Comment: TTF stands for (Time to failure), there is no calculation for DT (Downtime), 3jan and 4 jan is 0 because the equipment is running and coming to the calculation part its has to be like this 1 failure - TTF-24 TTR - 24, 2 failure - TTF-48 TTR-24 that's how I am trying to see it in excel sheet

Comment: It's a potentially interesting question, but I agree with @Harun24HR difficult to understand. Are you saying that you want the data grouped and summed by running column maybe, so you only have three rows containing 24,0,48,0? Can you show what the output should look  like plz? What is TTR and why do a TTF of 24 and a TTF of 48 both have a TTR of 24? Is Running always either zero or 24, or could it have values in between? Is DT always 24-Running?